# 2010: Calculated column multiple if statements

Tags: 2010, list, calculated-column

Currently, I have a formula to execute some number stripping for a column. When the user uses a card swipe, it outputs something like: ;502780133=0444?

The formula strips the semicolon and removes everything from the equal sign and on. Also, if a number isn't entered, it will display the error message "Enter SUID on Package Pickup"

```
=IF(ISERROR(RIGHT(LEFT(SUID,INT(FIND("=",SUID)-1)),LEN(LEFT(SUID,INT(FIND("=",SUID)-1)))-1)),"Enter the SUID on Package Pickup",RIGHT(LEFT(SUID,INT(FIND("=",SUID)-1)),LEN(LEFT(SUID,INT(FIND("=",SUID)-1)))-1))
```

I want to keep the error message intact, but I want the number stripping to occur only if a semicolon is found. This will help prevent errors when users manually enter the ID numbers.

Is this possible? If so, what would that formula look like?

Comment: Nicole, Have you tried adding another IF statement to check for the semicolon first?

Comment: That's what I'm looking to do, but with my beginner knowledge of calculated column formulas, I'm not sure how to do that within my current formula.

Comment: Okay. Let me give it a shot. Will get back to you shortly.

Comment: Nice site btw...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got some internal help and produced this answer:

```
=IF(
    LEFT(SUID,1)=";"
    ,MID(SUID,2,9)
    ,IF(LEN(TRIM(SUID))=0
        ,"Enter SUID on Pickup"
        ,IF(AND(LEN(TRIM(SUID))>0
            ,LEN(TRIM(SUID))<9)
            ,"Invalid SUID",SUID
           )
       )
   )
```

Answer (score 2):

It is easier if you build your Formula in partials/multiple Calculated Formulas, you can add a maximum of 48 Calculated Columns to a List and you don't have to use everyone in a View or Form.

So create a separate Column "NumberStripping" with you Formula

```
RIGHT(LEFT(SUID,FIND("=",SUID)-1),LEN(LEFT(SUID,FIND("=",SUID)-1))-1)
```

That is the part you want to wrap in an IF

```
IF( LEFT(SUID,1)=";" , [NumberStripping] , [NoNumberStripping] )
```

You will end up with multiple Columns, but much easier to read and debug; the number of Columns hardly effect performance

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just need a bit more of explanation. I put the IF statement in a column called SUID Number. I created NumberStripping with my original formula and NoNumberStripping as a normal single line of text column. When I go to save it says a formula is referring to a column that does not exist. Any idea why this may be happening?

Comment: If you created a Column [SUID Number] you need to use that displayname in other formulas. Those square brackets are required for Column names with spaces in them; not required for Columns that have no spaces

Comment: Sorry for my confusion. I just want to better understand your answer. I created a calculated column called SUID Number that has `IF( LEFT(SUID,1)=";" , [NumberStripping] , [NoNumberStripping] )` so it knows that when a semicolon is found, it will execute the NumberStripping calculated column with the formula `RIGHT(LEFT(SUID,FIND("=",SUID)-1),LEN(LEFT(SUID,FIND("=",SUID)-1))-1)`. Then I created NoNumberStripping as a regular single text column. The IF statement in SUID Number is pointing two valid columns. I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: If [SUID Number] references [NoNumberStripping] you will have to create that Column first, otherwise you get the Column does not exist error.

Answer (score 2):

Nicole,

Danny's solution should also work.

If you want to keep it in one formula, this should work.

```
=IF(LEFT(SUID,1)=";",IF(ISERROR(RIGHT(LEFT(SUID,INT(FIND("=",SUID)-1)),LEN(LEFT(SUID,INT(FIND("=",SUID)-1)))-1)),"Enter the SUID on Package Pickup",RIGHT(LEFT(SUID,INT(FIND("=",SUID)-1)),LEN(LEFT(SUID,INT(FIND("=",SUID)-1)))-1)),"Enter the SUID on Package Pickup")
```

Comment: Unfortunately this did not do the trick. When I enter in the numbers manually, it shows "Enter the SUID on Package Pickup". I only want that to appear when the column has no values in it.

Comment: So you want it to disappear once they start typing?

Comment: Try this.

=IF(LEFT(SUID,1)=";",IF(ISERROR(RIGHT(LEFT(SUID,INT(FIND("=",SUID)-1)),LEN(LEFT(SUID,INT(FIND("=",SUID)-1)))-1)),"Enter the SUID on Package Pickup",RIGHT(LEFT(SUID,INT(FIND("=",SUID)-1)),LEN(LEFT(SUID,INT(FIND("=",SUID)-1)))-1)),SUID)